# MacOS: Default focus for conditionally rendered TextField

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

**Update 1:**

- I tried calling `resetFocus` in the `onAppear` callback of the `TextField`, it didn't work, either.
- If the `TextField` is rendered with the initial app render, it gets auto-focused even without the `prefersDefaultFocus` modified. So maybe `prefersDefaultFocus` doesn't work for `TextField` at all?

**Original post:**

I am following [this guide by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Button/prefersDefaultFocus(_:in:)). After we click the button and the TextField gets rendered, I would like it to get auto-focused, but it doesn't.

If the initial value of `isEditing` is `true`, i.e. `TextField` is rendered with the initial app render, it does get auto-focused.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    @State private var textInput: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle editing") { isEditing = !isEditing }
            if isEditing {
                TextField("Write something", text: $textInput)
                    .prefersDefaultFocus(in: namespace)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling `resetFocus` in the two ways below, none of them helped.

```
    // ...

    @Environment(\.resetFocus) var resetFocus

    // ...

    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            resetFocus(in: namespace)
        }
    }

    // ...
```

```
    // ...

        @Environment(\.resetFocus) var resetFocus

    // ...

            if isEditing {
                TextField("Write something", text: $textInput)
                    .prefersDefaultFocus(in: namespace)
                    .background(textFieldDefaultFocusSetter)
            }

    // ...

    var textFieldDefaultFocusSetter: some View {
        resetFocus(in: namespace)
        return EmptyView()
    }
```

What am I missing? E.g. is `prefersDefaultFocus` only evaluated for views rendered during the initial render of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if `prefersDefaultFocus` does work with conditional views but in your case just set it explicitly. Add:

```
 @FocusState private var focus: Bool
```

and:

```
VStack {
        Button("Toggle editing") {
            isEditing = !isEditing
            focus = true
        }
        if isEditing {
            TextField("Write something", text: $textInput)
                .focused($focus)
//                    .prefersDefaultFocus(in: namespace)
        }
    }
}
```

This will set the focus to your `TextField` as soon as it appears.

Comment: Thank you, yes, this is what I ended up using for now. I wait some time before marking this as the accepted answer, maybe someone knows how to get `prefersDefaultFocus` to work.